# Permissions on Google Forms uploads

Tags: forms, permissions, google-forms

I have a Google Form that uploads some pictures that I want to be visible to anyone with a web browser.  Unfortunately they all arrive as private.   Is there any way to have them default to public instead of having to go through and mark them individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to share the folder.

1. Click `View Folder` on the bottom-right corner of the file upload question
2. Change the permission of the folder to `Anyone with the link` *

*The folder in 1. is the subfolder of the question you selected.
In case there are multiple file upload questions and you want to share all of them, change the permission of the parent folder instead.